# while(free) instead of while(true) in C whilst using macOS High Sierra

Tags: c, macos, while-loop, boolean, codeblocks

I recently was using a friends 2017 MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra, with Code::Blocks 13.12 compiled for Mac OSX. (As the Macintosh versions have not been updated since 2013).

When setting up Code::Blocks, macOS needed to install GCC from the Xcode console tools, which makes sense, but when I started creating a standard C console application inside Code::Blocks that used a while(true) loop. I got an error that 'true' doesn't work in context, but the term 'free' works instead. And sure enough, 'while(free)' does actually run and compile.

I have tried googling around for an explanation for what free is, but it seems that I am the only person on earth to have found this discrepancy. Is 'free' a mac specific boolean variable, and if so, what is it's opposite, is it still 'false'?

Any answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did someone suggest `while (free)`, or did you pick a random word…?

Comment: It was the compile error that I recieved attempting to compile using 'while(true)', I wish I could grab a screenshot of it, I probably could one day from now.

Comment: The compiler might have detected “free” as being closest to “true” in *spelling*, but that definitely doesn’t mean you should use it. `while (1)` or `for (;;)` would be correct.

Comment: This "X is not declared, maybe you meant Y?" feature of GCC has no complicated logic in it. It simply looks for an identified with a name similar to what you used. GCC suggested `while (free)` simply because it has no idea what `true` is and `free` sounds similar enough. In general, suggestions that GCC makes won't necessarily compile or work properly.

Comment: @Ry- My favorite would be `#include <stdbool.h>` at the top and `while (true)`, but that might be because I work in C++ a lot more than C.

Comment: @DanielH Probably. The classic idiomatic C way to do an infinite loop is `for (;;)`.

Comment: I apologize to everyone, but I just did some googling, I am used to Java and C#, but apparently, the correct looping system in C is 'while(1)' or 'for(;;)', still not sure why while(free) still works, according to some other answers, free() from stdlib.h can be used because it is not null as answer or existence.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I can't get GCC to suggest `free`; maybe Code::Blocks itself is making the suggestion or maybe it tunes GCC to be more liberal in its suggestions somehow.

Comment: @DanielH Did you include `<stdlib.h>`? [It works without any flags for me](https://godbolt.org/g/g1bYqS) (ignoring `-x c`, which forces C mode for .cpp files).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No, I didn't; I assumed NaturalistUbuntu would have mentioned that. I was also trying to figure out why `free` did work, though, and if I assume that's included it answers both questions.

Answer (score 3):

Well, `true` is a perfectly ordinary identifier in C. It is *NOT* a boolean literal. Look at [`<stdbool.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean) if you use C99 or later, and want a standard boolean type.

`free()` is a function defined in `<stdlib.h>`. Use that in a boolean context where it decays to a pointer, and like any other pointer to a function or object, it is not `NULL` and thus truthy enough.

Aside from that, (the compiler?) suggesting that alternative is certainly curious.

The idiomatic way in C to do what you want would be `for (;;)` (pronounced "forever"), though `while(1)` and myriad others work too.

Comment: but that would need 'free()' to either be defined as 'free' as an operator. Not a method, or anything else. Otherwise you would type 'while(free())' I believe.

Comment: @NaturalistUbuntu Elaborated slightly on the mechanics.

Answer (score 3):

Many C compilers trying to use something akin to a spellchecker to help guess an appropriate replacement for undeclared identifiers. As with most spellcheckers, this occasionally has hilarious results, and this is one of those times.

If you do not `#include <stdbool.h>` then `true` will not be defined. On the other hand, if you do `#include <stdlib.h>` then `free` will be declared as a function.

The standard conversions of C mean that a function will automatically be converted to a pointer to function, and a pointer to function can be automatically converted to boolean. So you can definitely use a function name in a boolean expression, where it will be converted to a true value.

If you look at `free` and `true` carefully, you will note their similarity: they both have vowels and consonants in the same place, and two of the four letters are identical; moreover, `f` looks a lot like a `t` (and, as noted in a comment, is nearby on the keyboard). So it's plausible that a spell-checker would guess that `true` was a misspelling of `free`.

People trying to reproduce this odd warning would be well-advised to recall that OP is using a Mac, and the default development environment on Macs uses Clang as its C/C++ compiler, and also aliases `gcc` to `clang`, presumably because so many people think that you use the `gcc` command to compile. (Hint: `c99` is specified by Posix.)

So here is the warning in all its glory (accompanied by another useful warning because I compiled with `-Wall`:

```
<stdin>:4:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'true'; did you mean 'free'?
  while(true) {
        ^~~~
        free
/usr/include/stdlib.h:563:13: note: 'free' declared here
extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
            ^
<stdin>:4:9: warning: address of function 'free' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Wpointer-bool-conversion]
  while(true) {
  ~~~~~ ^~~~
<stdin>:4:9: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
  while(true) {
        ^
        &
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Note: line 4 of the input is as quoted. Line 2 is `#include <stdlib.h>`. `stdbool.h` is not imported.

(Also, you can produce a similar spellcheck suggestion with gcc-8, if you happen to have it kicking around. But I'm pretty sure OP is using clang.)

Comment: I doubt any spellchecker is sophisticated enough to look at letter shapes, and most probably don't notice the vowel/consonant thing. Perhaps it notices that `f` and `t` are typed with the same finger in QWERTY, but I doubt even that.

Comment: (And the OP said that Code::Blocks installed GCC; does it lie to you so much that even if you *explicitly request GCC be installed* it'll give you Clang?) It looks like GCC will only display the second warning after you "fix the typo".

Comment: @DanielH: He didn't say that. He said "When setting up Code::Blocks, macOS needed to ***install GCC from the Xcode console tools***", and the Xcode console tools, as I indicated, will install clang and then call it gcc. (It's also called "clang" and "c99".) If you later really install gcc, then you will have two compilers. But you won't get it from the Xcode tools.

Comment: Also, you'd be surprised how sophisticated spellchecker algorithms are. And they still make hilarious mistakes. :) They definitely consider words which differ only in vowels much closer than words which have significant consonant differences, typically because they try to use phonetic comparison. The ones which consider letter shapes are important for correction of OCR'd documents.

Comment: Yeah, I'd expect OCR to consider letter shapes, but unless there's a significant amount of OCRed C code, I wouldn't expect Clang or GCC to consider it. The values and finger positions are more plausible, but I'd still bet it's mostly based on half the letters being shared. Now I'm curious though and will see if I can actually find it.

Comment: @DanielH: Spellcheckers don't use letter shapes per se. But they have a concept of similarity of letters, so that, for example, if a correctly spelled word can be created by replacing "z" with "s", that will be chosen over a word which replaces the "z" with a "w". Whether a non-OCR spellchecker would consider "f" to "t" than "g" I don't know, but it wouldn't surprise me in the least.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/175998/discussion-between-daniel-h-and-rici).

Answer (score 2):

In C, `true` is not a built-in identifier, but [only declared in `<stdbool.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean). If you don't include that, then `true` isn't defined. That's probably part of how Code::Blocks or something it called got confused. For some reason, it thought `true` was a typo for `free`. It wasn't; you meant `true` and it made a bad suggestion.

What did happen when you tried `while (free)` is that the compiler saw the [*function* `free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free), saw that you weren't calling it as a function, and converted it to a [function pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions). A function pointer acts as true when it isn't `NULL`, and this one pointed to `free`, so it works like `while (true)`.

If you included `<stdlib.h>`, then the compiler would be able to compile with `free` and you'd get the infinite loop. If you didn't, I don't know why `while (free)` would work; I can't get that to happen for me.

Answer (score 1):

Usually `free` is the [standard] function for freeing memory from allocated from the heap via `malloc` et. al.

To *invoke* it, you'd do something like: `free(my_pointer)`

But, when you *just* specify `free` [or any other function for that matter] *without* any parentheses, this means you want the *address* of the `free` function/symbol itself [*without* actually calling/invoking the function]. The normal "address of" operator [unary `&`] (e.g. `&free`) is *not* required for a function as it would be for a scalar like `int`

`free` and `&free` generate the same code but leaving off the `&` is more idiomatic.

Here is a snippet that *will* invoke the `free` function and illustrates the usage of just `free` without parens:

```
#include <malloc.h>

void *my_pointer;
void (*myfree)(void *);
void (*myfree2)(void *);

void
foo(void)
{

    // set pointer to function from the address of the free function
    myfree = free;

    // invoke the free function via indirect pointer
    (*myfree)(my_pointer);

    // this allows a pointer to function to behave syntactically like a
    // direct function call
    myfree(my_pointer);

    // set pointer to function from previous pointer to function
    myfree2 = myfree;

    // do the same thing as above
    myfree2(my_pointer);
}
```

Just for fun, you could say: `printf("%p\n",free)` and compare this against the link map of your program.

Since [virtually] all function addresses are non-zero, doing `while (free)` is equivalent to `while (&free)` and [if not detected/optimized at compile time is a slightly slower version that] has the effect of: `while (1)`

If you compile with `-Wall`, `gcc` will produce:

```
warning: the address of ‘free’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Waddress]
  while (free);
         ^~~~
```